# How to exhibit VNC implementation on genymotion ?

Tags: android, vnc-server

I need expert advice here.
I was trying to deploy `VNC server (DroidVNC)` on Android device and trying to get a VNC session on my Ubuntu PC.
So far everything is good. Using `TightVNC` (as client) on ubuntu, I can access phone on the computer.

I want to implement the same in `genymotion` emulator. 
I faced problem in installing DroidVNC on genymotion emulator as genymotion is based on `x86 architecture`.

I ported genymotion to ARM architecture and was successful in doing so. But still DroidVNC is not working in genymotion.

Can anyone help me out with it ? I am not able to catch hold the main issue regarding why DroidVNC is not running in emulator.

If you have any other alternative where I can access phone on PC, then please do share it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks .

Comment: Can you please elaborate the steps you used to get it work on android device. I want to implement the same with Android and Ubuntu